# Force http on two pages using the .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https

I would like to redirect to pages from HTTPS to HTTP using the .htaccess file.

I have added the code for one page but when I add it for page2 it gives the site a redirect error.

Here is my code that works for one page going from HTTPS to HTTP in the .htaccess  and I also make sure the .htaccess is in that directory with the files I want to be redirected as well.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page1.php$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]


RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page1.php$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But when I add it like this below it doesn't work and I get a redirect error.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page1.php$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page2.php$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]


RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page1.php$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page2.php$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I would like the pages to go to HTTP only using the .htaccess file without error:

http://mywebsite.com/page1.php http://mywebsite.com/page2.php

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The correct code I needed is below:

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(page2.php$|page1.php$) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(page2.php$|page1.php$) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]